# truffle compile error

Tags: truffle, solc, solcjs

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0.5.16')
    at VersionRange.getSolcVersionFileName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/dist/compilerSupplier/loadingStrategies/VersionRange.js:204:1)
    at VersionRange.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/dist/compilerSupplier/loadingStrategies/VersionRange.js:171:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/dist/compilerSupplier/loadingStrategies/VersionRange.js:5:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Truffle v5.5.11 (core: 5.5.11)
Node v16.10.0


> truffle version 
Truffle v5.5.11 (core: 5.5.11)
Ganache v^7.0.4
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.10.0
Web3.js v1.5.3
```

Comment: @Ismael ty, i have already solve this problem

Comment: That's very good, you could add the solution as answer!

Answer (score 1):

use compilers in truffle.config.js  to change the solc version to match the contract's solidity version. need to mention that i use solc-select to change my solc golab version before truffle compile.

```
    compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "native",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  }
```